# Add / Remove items from JInternalFrame icon menu

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

Is there a way to add/remove items in the `JInternalFrame` icon menu (is that what it is called?) ?

[image]

Thanks to @camickr, I was able to dig into the UIManager a little bit using [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/). What I found was this: I printed out the `Nimbus` LookAndFeel `HashMap`

```
    for(Entry<Object, Object> entry : SwingUtils.getUIDefaultsOfClass(JInternalFrame.class).entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey().toString() + " ----------- " + entry.getValue().toString());
        System.out.println("*********************************");
    }
```

And this is what appeared:

```
closeButton"[Pressed].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneCloseButtonPainter@1dddec9e
*********************************
titleAlignment ----------- CENTER
*********************************
titleFont ----------- java.awt.Font[family=SansSerif,name=sansserif,style=bold,size=12]
*********************************
iconifyButton".contentMargins ----------- javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=9,left=9,bottom=9,right=9]
*********************************
iconifyButton"[Pressed+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneIconifyButtonPainter@2dfbc274
*********************************
menuButton".WindowNotFocused ----------- WindowNotFocused
*********************************
maximizeButton".contentMargins ----------- javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=9,left=9,bottom=9,right=9]
*********************************
maxFrameIconSize ----------- javax.swing.plaf.DimensionUIResource[width=18,height=18]
*********************************
maximizeButton"[MouseOver].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@4e2899d0
*********************************
disabledText ----------- DerivedColor(color=0,0,0 parent=text offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=0,0,0
*********************************
backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFramePainter@4b8a4ec6
*********************************
InternalFrameUI ----------- javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel
*********************************
closeButton"[Disabled].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneCloseButtonPainter@38d9e447
*********************************
menuButton"[MouseOver+WindowNotFocused].iconPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMenuButtonPainter@6ef66f2f
*********************************
menuButton".test ----------- am InternalFrameTitlePane.menuButton
*********************************
menuButton"[MouseOver].iconPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMenuButtonPainter@74fdaf92
*********************************
textForeground ----------- DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Enabled+WindowMaximized+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@67e61dd0
*********************************
iconifyButton"[MouseOver+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneIconifyButtonPainter@48a5d3d5
*********************************
closeButton"[Enabled].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneCloseButtonPainter@5a5cbad
*********************************
iconifyButton".WindowNotFocused ----------- WindowNotFocused
*********************************
foreground ----------- DerivedColor(color=0,0,0 parent=text offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=0,0,0
*********************************
menuButton".icon ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusIcon@26cb216f
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Enabled+WindowMaximized].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@47decdc0
*********************************
maximizeButton"[MouseOver+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@74961d1c
*********************************
contentMargins ----------- javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0]
*********************************
menuButton".contentMargins ----------- javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0]
*********************************
iconifyButton".States ----------- Enabled,MouseOver,Pressed,Disabled,Focused,Selected,WindowNotFocused
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Pressed].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@2b515510
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Pressed+WindowMaximized].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@68a7a3a7
*********************************
background ----------- DerivedColor(color=214,217,223 parent=control offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=214,217,223
*********************************
closeButton".contentMargins ----------- javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=9,left=9,bottom=9,right=9]
*********************************
menuButton"[Enabled].iconPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMenuButtonPainter@73d6af61
*********************************
menuButton"[Pressed].iconPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMenuButtonPainter@139444b1
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Enabled].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@27f5ad1c
*********************************
font ----------- javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=SansSerif,name=sansserif,style=plain,size=12]
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Pressed+WindowMaximized+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@72381dc2
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Disabled+WindowMaximized].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@4229e623
*********************************
windowBindings ----------- [Ljava.lang.Object;@2d10609a
*********************************
maximizeButton"[MouseOver+WindowMaximized].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@4cc425c4
*********************************
menuButton"[Enabled+WindowNotFocused].iconPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMenuButtonPainter@618b8e3b
*********************************
menuButton"[Disabled].iconPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMenuButtonPainter@1126f585
*********************************
iconifyButton"[MouseOver].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneIconifyButtonPainter@14c0f78f
*********************************
closeButton".WindowNotFocused ----------- WindowNotFocused
*********************************
disabled ----------- DerivedColor(color=214,217,223 parent=control offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=214,217,223
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Enabled+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@8bcd7ee
*********************************
States ----------- Enabled,WindowFocused
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Pressed+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@26044ebd
*********************************
iconifyButton"[Pressed].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneIconifyButtonPainter@64cd6dca
*********************************
closeButton"[Enabled+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneCloseButtonPainter@5f203fe5
*********************************
actionMap ----------- javax.swing.plaf.basic.LazyActionMap@82f0668
*********************************
InternalFrameTitlePaneUI ----------- javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel
*********************************
closeButton"[Pressed+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneCloseButtonPainter@22b1513e
*********************************
menuButton".States ----------- Enabled,MouseOver,Pressed,Disabled,Focused,Selected,WindowNotFocused
*********************************
WindowFocused ----------- WindowFocused
*********************************
maximizeButton"[Disabled].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@274ccf3d
*********************************
maximizeButton".States ----------- Enabled,MouseOver,Pressed,Disabled,Focused,Selected,WindowNotFocused,WindowMaximized
*********************************
closeButton"[MouseOver+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneCloseButtonPainter@23b9c1f3
*********************************
iconifyButton"[Disabled].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneIconifyButtonPainter@223dd567
*********************************
iconifyButton"[Enabled].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneIconifyButtonPainter@9856ec1
*********************************
maximizeButton"[MouseOver+WindowMaximized+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonPainter@172a45c9
*********************************
closeButton".States ----------- Enabled,MouseOver,Pressed,Disabled,Focused,Selected,WindowNotFocused
*********************************
menuButton"[Pressed+WindowNotFocused].iconPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneMenuButtonPainter@584b9b00
*********************************
closeButton"[MouseOver].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneCloseButtonPainter@4bad4a49
*********************************
maximizeButton".WindowNotFocused ----------- WindowNotFocused
*********************************
maximizeButton".WindowMaximized ----------- WindowMaximized
*********************************
iconifyButton"[Enabled+WindowNotFocused].backgroundPainter ----------- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.InternalFrameTitlePaneIconifyButtonPainter@5de8256f
*********************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can remove them (with out creating your own custom UI which is too complicated for me).

You should be able to disable them. Check out the `JInternalFrame` API constructors for a way to set the properties to false. Or you can use the setter methods to disable a given property individually.

Edit:

Just noticed that the default LAF on Windows does not have that menu, so it definitely is a LAF issue.

Edit 2:

Maybe as a hack you can use Darryl's [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) to get a List of all JMenuItem components defined for the internal frame. Then you might be able to simply remove the menu items from its parent JMenu.

Edit 3:

I suggested to get a list of the JMenuItem components, not the UIDefaults. This was assuming that the BasicInternalFrameUI used a JMenuBar, JMenu and JMenuItems. This assumption was correct.

Well as it turns out the Metal LAF extend the basic LAF and doesn't add the JMenubar to the title pane of the internal frame. Instead just paints an icon at the top left which explain why there is no system menu.

However, the Windows LAF actually uses a custom painted JLabel to display the icon for the system menu and then just responds to a mousePressed event to display a popup menu. So for the Window LAF you can use SwingUtils to find this label and just remove the MouseListener from the label. The "frame" variable below is your internal frame.

```
java.util.List<JLabel> labels = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JLabel.class, frame, true);

for (JLabel label: labels)
{
    System.out.println(label.getClass().getName());

    MouseListener[] ml = (MouseListener[])label.getListeners(MouseListener.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < ml.length; i++)
        label.removeMouseListener( ml[i] );
}
```

As I suggested earlier, this really is just a hack and should probably not be used since it will not be a cross platform solution.

Comment: 1) "too complicated for me" is a shock coming from you. 2) The Windows LAF omits the icon, but the menu is still there me.

Comment: I should have said the cross platform LAF (ie. the Metal LAF), which is the default if you don't specify a LAF. The Windows LAF is as you described.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, `Metal` does omit the menu. Interesting.

Comment: Why would I want to remove the mouse listener? I'm interested in altering the contents of the Menu...

Comment: For some reason I missed the "add" and thought you only wanted to remove the items (if you notice my original answer), so I was proceeding along this path. So if you want to modify the menu, then you need to modify the LAF. You can start by looking at `WindowsInternalFrameTitlePane`. It contains a protected method `addSystemMenuItems(...)` which is used to set up the popup menu.